# dpkg giving error "Is a directory"

Tags: debian, packaging, dpkg

I am trying to create a Debain .deb package. Package is being created successfully but I am getting following error when I try to install it:

```
 unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//opt': Is a directory
```

The package directory structure is :

```
.
└── DEBIAN
    ├── control
    ├── opt
    │   └── myDir
    │       └── myfile
    ├── postinst
    └── preinst
```

In preinst I've - `mkdir -p /opt/myDir` postinst is empty

If I try to install package on a different host, I get below error:

> package control info rmdir of `opt' didn't say not a dir: Directory
>   not empty

Any ideas?

Comment: First, you don't want to create directories in preinst. Dpkg will create this as necessary. Second, you don't want to install Debian packages in /opt. That is a violation of Debian Policy and the FHS. Having said that, I don't know exactly why you are seeing the error.

Comment: Please post your entire `preinst` script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your directory layout is wrong. It should be like this:

```
.
├── opt
│   └── myDir
│       └── myfile
└── DEBIAN
    ├── control
    ├── postinst
    └── preinst
```

After you build your package you can test its format with [lintian](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/lintian/):

```
lintian my-package.deb
```

I had the same problem as you and lintian helped me fix it.